# Why do I get a segmentation fault when adding ltalloc with MinGW

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, pthreads, mingw32, thread-local-storage

I tried to build my application with [ltalloc](https://code.google.com/p/ltalloc/wiki/Main). I tried it with MinGW32 4.9.1 and MinGW64-32 4.9.2.
It compiles and links fine but when I run it a Segmentation Fault occurs. Debugging pinpointed the problem to the following code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#pragma weak pthread_once
#pragma weak pthread_key_create
#pragma weak pthread_setspecific
static pthread_key_t pthread_key;
static pthread_once_t init_once = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
static void init_pthread_key() { pthread_key_create(&pthread_key, release_thread_cache); }
static thread_local int thread_initialized = 0;
static void init_pthread_destructor()//must be called only when some block placed into a thread cache's free list
{
    if (unlikely(!thread_initialized))
    {
        thread_initialized = 1;
        if (pthread_once)
        {
            pthread_once(&init_once, init_pthread_key);  // <--- THIS CAUSES THE SEGSEGV
            pthread_setspecific(pthread_key, (void*)1);//set nonzero value to force calling of release_thread_cache() on thread terminate
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know both versions support thread-local storage natively. The Wiki of of ltalloc also wrote the following:

> Warning: in some builds of MinGW there is a problem with emutls and order of execution of thread destructor (all thread local variables destructed before it), and termination of any thread will lead to application crash.

Unfortunately this warning doesn't tell me anything. Googling it also didn't make me smarter.

Comment: Why do you do initialise the global `init_pthread_key` using a thread specific variable (`thread_initialized`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the blue, try this:

```
static void init_pthread_key(void) 
{ 
  if (pthread_key_create)
  {
    pthread_key_create(&pthread_key, release_thread_cache); 
  }
}
```

---

Also adding full error checking to the `pthread_*` might not only help during debugging.

Comment: This definition stops pthread_once from crashing. But now a sigsegv occurs in pthread_setspecific. What does this mean? How can I enable full error checking of pthread stuff?

Comment: @JackSabbath: Same issue then. So just test `pthread_setspecific` for being different from `NULL` before calling it. With "*full error checking*" I am referreing to the possibility to test the `pthread_*` functions' return value for indicating an error.

Comment: Yes, this function is also not found and therefore your suggestions avoid the SIGSEGV. However, I think this doesn't solve the problem. The idea behind these function calls is to have a callback, which will clean up the thread_local data (they can't have a destructor, since thread_local data need to be trivial destructable for GCC. If I won't call these functions, there will be no cleanup. What reason could exist so these functions are 0? The compiler and the linker don't complain, so I don't understand how it's even possible that the functions are not found.

Comment: @JackSabbath: "*this doesn't solve the problem*" it **does** solve the issues you are asking about.  I however wonder why the functions in question are declared weak if the are essentially necessary for the application to work?

Comment: I wrote my intention to use ltalloc. Not calling functions, which are necessary for a error-free execution, will not solve a problem. However, thank you for your help :) I also don't know why the author declared them weak. I found a workaround with using boost::this_thread::at_thread_exit instead of pthread_key_create.